# How add image in navbar on website homepage with logout button in html

Tags: html, css, web, navbar

I’m start working on a project based on database designing using HTML website. I'm making a website for the purpose of online food order system.

while working on navbar of website’s homepage, how to add title at the left side of navbar and logout button with an image?

I have worked on the following code but I do not get desired outcome.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/150x50?text=Logo" alt="">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Your HTML is not valid. See the snippet I made and formatted. Also it looks like you are using Bootstrap. Add the necessary files to the snippet

Comment: What kind of error is there sir@mplungjan

Comment: `</button> div>`